# Generate serie of queries in PENTAHO

Tags: automation, data-warehouse, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

How do I build a general query based in a list of tables and run/export the results?

Here is my conceptual structure

[conceptual structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBLUh.png)

Basically the from clause in query would be inserted by the table rows.
After that, each schema.table with true result returned must be stored in a text archive.

Could someone help me?

Comment: I think you should solve your task with one pé these steps: Execute SQL script, Dynamic SQL row or Execute row SQL script.

Answer (score 0):

As pentaho doesn't support loops, it's a bit complicated. Basically you read a list of tables and copy the rows to the result and then you have a foreach-job that runs for every row in the result.

I use this setup for all jobs like this: [How to process a Kettle transformation once per filename](http://www.timbert.net/doku.php?id=techie:kettle:jobs:processtransonceperfile)

In the linked example, it is used to process files, but it can be easily adapted to your use.